# How do I stop executing code inside the useEffect() hook when a React.js component renders for the first time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a requirement not to execute the code inside `useEffect()` when the component renders for the first time. For that, I defined a variable outside of the component function and set it to `true`. And then I checked if the variable is `true` inside `useEffect()` hook and if it was `true`, I set the variable to `false` and set it to `return` as shown below. But the code is not working as I expected. The code inside `useEffect()` executes regardless.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

let isInitial = true;

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('First');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }
    setMessage('Executed');
  }, []);

  return <p>{message}</p>;
}

export default App;
```

I wanted to print **'First'** inside the `<p>`. But the result was **'Executed'** inside `<p>` which is not what I expected.

Comment: your code seems to be ok , I tried that in and it shows 'First'

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh for me, it shows "First" briefly and then it gets replaced with "Executed". I created this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-microservice-3z4vsd?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate the issue I'm having

Comment: It is probably because you are in react strict mode and running react 18.
Try removing <React.StrictMode> from your app file and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) would be the problem. It renders your component twice in development mode. So the result would be not what you need in your code.

In addition, I suggest you to change the `let` statement to `useState`. Changing mutable `let` in the `useEffect` would cause unexpectable side effects. Using `useState` would be more predictable, React way.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("First");
  const [isInitial, setIsInitial] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitial) {
      setIsInitial(false);
    } else {
      // Do what you want excepts first render
    }
  }, [isInitial]);

  return <p>{message}</p>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jay. Yes, Strict mode was the issue. I will change `let` variable to a state inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote should result `<p>First</p>`, unless `<React.StrictMode>` has wrapped around your main component ([StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application and the checks are run in development mode only).
It causes `App` component to render twice and `useEffect` callback function will be called twice too(although the `useEffect` has `[]` dependency).

You should remove that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, @mahooresorkh. Yes, `<React.StrictMode>` was the issue. When I removed `<React.StrictMode>` wrapper, the code worked fine.